# viewpager showing on the middle

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-viewpager

I used viewpager which is inside the scrollview.In this viewpager I have banner image,Title,next and previous button,content body.below viewpager ads,related contents list etc.

All the thing Inside scrollview except only footer.

**How to show viewpager after action bar and related contents should be on offscreen scroll and footer should be fixed at the bottom**

Here is XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rl_contentDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/footerId_slider"
            layout="@layout/footer"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- for show footer -->

    <RelativeLayout   
        android:id="@+id/header1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/rl_top1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/headerView_pager_gallery_slider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/galleryviewpager_height"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ibLeft"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/left"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ibRight"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/right"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtExtraNews_gallery_slider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/extra_news"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_header"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageBrkLine_gallery_slider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtExtraNews_gallery_slider"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/red_header"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <com.org.AmarUjala.news.utility.NonScrollListView
                    android:id="@+id/cdetailListExtraNews_gallery_slider"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageBrkLine_gallery_slider"
                    android:background="@color/grey"
                    android:divider="#ddd"
                    android:dividerHeight="1px"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:splitMotionEvents="true"></com.org.AmarUjala.news.utility.NonScrollListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:weightSum` for this purpose,

At the end that is **outside ScrollView add this LinearLayout** and in that **include your layout** that you want to use in footer

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center|bottom">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_footer_new" />
    </LinearLayout>
```